# How to update world inorder to get next iteration of DEAD/ALIVE cells

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I am writing the code for Game of Life. With little progress.

The problem is not very evident for me but I have a suspicion to why I can't iterate my world.

Description of what my code is supposed to do:

In my main-function I have declared the dimensions for my array/world.

a characters array `field` where I can store each element as `DEAD` or `ALIVE`.

a declared array `counts` which is passed on to a function `PrintWorld` where the array stores the amount of neighbours each cell has.

a function `intitField(rows,cols,field)` which initializes my `field` array.

Lastly I have my function `printWorld(rows,cols,field,counts)` which is supposed to perform the neccessary operations inorder to update my World.

A summary of what `printWorld` does and how it interacts with other functions:

What `printWorld` does is:

prints the current intilized field. While being the user presses enter, this being enforced by a while-loop.

inside the while-loop is a function `evolve` which should update the world every time the user presses enter.

Inside the `evolve` function we will find a function `CellNeighbour`.

`CellNeighbour` makes use of the array declared in my main-function `counts[rows][cols]`.

Inside  `CellNeighbour` we store the amount of ALIVE neighbours each cells has inside the array `counts`.

When all ALIVE neighbours have been stored in `counts` we continue with the rest of `evolve`.

Now I can use this fact inorder to check the conditions imposed by game of life.

As you can see in `evolve`, next iteration of cell is being prepared by checking the conditions.

Then determining if next cell should be DEAD or ALIVE.

When all the cell for next generation have been determined we continue with the function `evolve`.

Now we get to the function `updateWorld`.

All `updateWorld` does is that it takes all the newly stored cells for the next generation and stores it in the character array `field[rows][cols].current`

Thus when we return to the function `printWorld` I should get new values for `field[i][j].current` inside the while-loop. And the new generation of cells should be printed.

Unfortunaley I can not find what i'm doing wrong. However I do suspect that when calling functions some of the arrays lose their stored information. But I am not able to confirm this.

You're able to find my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Constants, representation of states */
#define ALIVE 'X'
#define DEAD '.'

/* Declaration of data structure */
typedef struct{
  char current;
  char next;
} cell;

/* Declaration of functions */
void initField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadGlider(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadSemaphore(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void printWorld(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols],int counts[rows][cols]);
void CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols]);
void evolve(const int rows,const int cols,cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols]);
void updateWorld(int const rows, int const cols, cell field[rows][cols]);



/* Function:    main
* Description: Start and run games, interact with the user.
* Input:       About what initial structure and whether to step or exit.
* Output:      Information to the user, and the game field in each step.
*/

int main(void) {

  const int rows = 20;
  const int cols = 20;
  cell field[rows][cols];
  int counts[rows][cols];

  initField(rows,cols, field);
  printWorld(rows,cols,field,counts);
  //CellNeighbour(rows,cols,field,counts);//test


  /*Used for testing*/
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
      printf("%d ", counts[i][j]);// updated in CellNeighbour
    }
    printf("\n");
  }




  return 0;
}


/* Function:    initField
* Description: Initialize all the cells to dead, then asks the user about
*              which structure to load, and finally load the structure.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void initField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  for (int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++) {
      field[r][c].current = DEAD;
    }
  }

  printf("Select field spec to load ([G]lider, [S]emaphore)");


  int ch = getchar();

  /* Ignore following newline */
  if (ch != '\n') {
    getchar();
  }

  switch (ch) {
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
    loadGlider(rows, cols, field);
    break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
    loadSemaphore(rows, cols, field);
  }
}


/* Function:    loadGlider
* Description: Inserts a glider into the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void loadGlider(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  field[0][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[1][2].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][0].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][2].current = ALIVE;
}


/* Function:    loadSemaphore
* Description: Inserts a semaphore into the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void loadSemaphore(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  field[8][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[8][2].current = ALIVE;
  field[8][3].current = ALIVE;
}




/* Function:    printWorld
* Description: Prints the current field
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/


void printWorld(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols]){

  char c = '\n';

  while(c == '\n'){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        printf("%c ", field[i][j].current);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    evolve(rows,cols,field,counts);

    printf("EXIT PROGRAM PRESS ANY CHARACTERS\n");
    printf("TO GET NEXT ITERATION PRESS ENTER\n");
    c = getchar();

    if(c != '\n'){ //exits the loop
      break;
    }

  }
}

void evolve(const int rows,const int cols,cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols]){

  CellNeighbour(rows, cols,field,counts);

  for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
    for(int j =0;j<cols;j++){
        if (field[i][j].current == ALIVE && counts[i][j] == 2){
    field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
  }
  else if (counts[i][j] == 3){
    field[i][j].next = ALIVE;
  }
  else{
    field[i][j].next = DEAD;
  }
}


    //Updating the next iteration, below:

    updateWorld(rows, cols, field);

  }
}



  void CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols]){

    int i,j;


    for(i = 0;i<rows;i++){
      for(j =0;j<cols;j++){
        counts[i][j] =0;
      }
    }

    for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
      for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
        if(i>0 && j>0){
          if(field[i-1][j-1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(j>0){
          if(field[i][j-1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(j>0){
          if(field[i+1][j-1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(i<rows-1){
          if(field[i+1][j].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(i <rows-1 && j <cols-1){
          if(field[i+1][j+1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(j<cols-1){
          if(field[i][j+1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(i>0 && j<cols-1){
          if(field[i-1][j+1].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
        if(i>0){
          if(field[i-1][j].current == ALIVE){
            counts[i][j]++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void updateWorld(int const rows, int const cols, cell field[rows][cols]){

    for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
      for(int j =0;j<cols;j++){
        field[i][j].current = field[i][j].next;
      }
    }
  }
```

When printworld prints out the intial field. Say the we chose the field spec Glider which initializes the field with the coordinates:

```
  field[0][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[1][2].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][0].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][2].current = ALIVE;
```

I get:

```
. X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
X X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

So after the cells have evolved(updated) once I should get:

```
. . x . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
X . X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Here is a video of what I get when I initialize the field with a glider spec:

https://streamable.com/rvbzw

It should however "glide" from the upper-left corner of the screen to the lower-right side.

Any ideas  to why it does this?

Comment: In initField, try initialising the `next` values to be DEAD as well.  Alternatively (and in retrospect, a better approach), in evolve, set your criteria for setting ALIVE, then simply have a big `else` catchall afterwards to set to DEAD.

Comment: Hey @racraman I forgot to mention it. But for the assigment I was given a template of the code which included ``intitField`` and all the functions inside. These are the only function which I am not allowed to modify. unfortunately

Comment: OK, then go with my (in retrospect better) approach that I added to my comment :)  The problem could well be that at present the `next` values are not being set - ie. they're left at something other than ALIVE or DEAD.  To fix, eveolve must explicitly set EVERY cell's `next` value to ALIVE or DEAD.

Comment: Hmm. So I added:     
``else{ field[rows][cols].next = DEAD;}`` inside the nested for-loop for ``evolve`` but the output stays the same :/

Comment: OK, could you update the code in the question :)

Comment: @racraman I've now updated the code above to include the else statement :)

Comment: Not quite what I meant - that `else` only applies to the immediately preceding `if`.  Instead, combine all those separate `if` statements to make the entire body of the loop as ONE single if..else - ie. `if (condition || condition || ....) { next = ALIVE; } else { next = DEAD; }`

Comment: @racraman I got a hold of my lecturer and I was allowed to modify ``initField``. I now used your first suggestion of intializing the next cells with DEAD.

Things work  now, in the sense that the cells are updating and following some pattern. However not really the pattern I would like:


Here is a video of what happens: https://streamable.com/rvbzw

Where it should glide from one side to the other. Any idea why it does this?

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned in the comments, it’s better if you follow my second suggestion of modifying evolve.  Have you tried that, and if so could you post the code ?

Comment: @racraman I've now updated it. I did not know however how to treat the condition where a cell is DEAD but it has exactly 3 ALIVE neighbours. So I made it into a seperate if statement. I also fixed the elements to ``i`` and ``j`` instead of ``cols`` and ``rows`` for ``evolve`` and also ``updateWorld`` so it atleast should update properly

Comment: @racraman I've updated ``evolve`` it once more. Now it works without having to intializing all the other cells as DEAD in ``initField``. Is this what you had in mind? :)

Comment: I solved it! All it took was to move ``updateWorld`` down so that it updates after the last for-loop.